# Struts - extra proprty

Tags: java, struts

What happens if in the HTML I send one property(or more) that don't exist in the mapped action form in struts?

Comment: Don't you think you should try it?

Comment: of course I tried it..., I would like to get a better understanding of this case.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able even to send them. Your JSP page won't compile, because it will not be aware of any properties you declared in form if they won't be defined in struts action form.

Comment: This isn't really correct; you could simply create a hidden form element with a property not in the `ActionForm`--you don't *have* to use the Struts tags to render form inputs.

Comment: I'm talking about just sending attributes that I didn't defined in the action form, and not getting them in the JSP....

Comment: Since the "property" in JSP refers to the form or other beans property, it should throw some mapping/bean utility exception if those properties are not defined in any of your mapped form or beans.